# HTML Table: Stopping Word Breaks From Jumping To The Left Side Of The Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a web project that involves a simple HTML table. The elements in the table display fine and all when the page is wide enough, but when the page is too narrow to display the elements on the same line, the overflow jumps to the next line, but below the table header, which is too far left from the start of the element. This also happens when line breaks are introduced. I want to be able to stop this from happening and keep the multi-line elements in a sort of fixed box where the line breaks don't ignore rules defined in the css properties, but without completely reworking the table. Please help make this happen. I have provided an example of this below.

Markup:

```
<table class="rwd-table">
<tr>
<td data-th="Column 1"><span>Example 1</span></td>
<td data-th="Column 2"><span>Hello World</span></td>
<td data-th="Column 3"><span>I am a long span element. </span></td>
<td data-th="Column 4"><span>I am an even longer span element in this table. New lines will jump to the very left of the table when the page is small enough.</span>
<td data-th="Column 5"><span>I am a long span element too.<br>I am also bugged :(</span></td>
<td data-th="Column 6"><span>1234567890</span></td>
</table>
```

A working example: https://codepen.io/Spotlightsrule/pen/EXoJdB

Comment: Why not put the 'Columns' in their own `td` and the span content in a new `td`?

Comment: If you want a structure like this then use .rwd-table td span { display:inline-block; } . Otherwise you also use different td for columns and for span.

Comment: Doing it like that is by far the best solution, but if you cannot change the HTML at all, you can float the `::before` to the left and use `display:block` for the spans. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjEveB

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have resolved the issue using the modified codepen.